# mongodb store and sort by color

Tags: mongodb

I'm going to create a database with a lot of RGB colors within a document. Later on I would like so sort, filter them by color/closeness.

Do you have any tips'n tricks for me? How should i store them?

Thanks!

Comment: What's your formula for "closeness"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by storing them as Integers as described in the processing reference.

http://processing.org/reference/color_datatype.html
http://processing.org/reference/rightshift.html